# How to display content for specific user

Tags: views

I created a content type Report. One of the fields name is MyUser and field type is EntityReference. For this field, widget type is SelectList and Target type is User.

I added two contents: Content1 and Content2. I selected UserA for the MyUser field in Content1 and I selected UserB for the MyUser field in content 2.

Now, I created a page view to select the content for the logged in user. If userA logged in, he should see only content1 and if userB logged in, he should see only content2. I thought I needed to add a filter criteria/relationship in view.

How to add the filter criteria/relationship to meet the above requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an explicit relationship to the user, and mark it as required. After that you will be able to add a new filter criterion to your view: `User: Current`.

[image]

Comment: 1. Relationship: Add > Entity Reference: Referenced Entity > Marked as Required > Saved the View. 
2. Filter Criteria: Add > User: Current > Relationship field displays 'Entity Reference: Referenced Entity' > Select Yes for "Is the logged in" > Saved.


3. Logged in as UserA > I saw only Content1 and Logged in as UserB > I saw only Content2.

Comment: So ... question answered? Or did I misread your question?

Comment: Sorry to confuse you. Question is answered. I also voted you.

Comment: Then please [mark the answer as "accepted"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/153938).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your problem but for what i've understand you could resolve using [Content access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) module it permit you to associate a specific content type to a role ( user group )

Hope to help you