# User Specific content on a page - Beginner question

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms, entities

So there are a few threads that might be my answer, but it doesn't seem like the modules are for Drupal 8.

So what I'm trying to do is to create a page that filters its content to display only content that references the user without building a new page per person.

The webpage itself would read as something along the lines of the following.
http://www.website.com/UserSpecific/
However, if the user didn't have any content referencing them the page would be empty. However, if they had content referencing them they would be able to view that content, and no other user would be able to.

Is that how the system works to begin with in Drupal 8 so long as it's referencing a particular user? Or is there another step in getting this done?

---

The threads I'm referring to are the following.
[Tag users in a content field to create user-specific content listings](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/166505/tag-users-in-a-content-field-to-create-user-specific-content-listings)

[How to display content for specific user](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/176678/how-to-display-content-for-specific-user)

Comment: Yep you can do that out-of-the-box

Comment: Is there any sort of documentation or indicator on how to do this? Or would you mind helping describe the process for me?

Comment: The accepted answer on the 2nd question you linked to should be all you need, the structure/UI for views hasn't really changed since D7

Comment: That should work in the same in way in 8.x. Views and reference fields are in core, you don't need anything else.